# Exclude columns from apply function based on column name

Tags: r

I have some data:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c('word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word','word'), 
                 v1_open = c('word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word','word'),
                 v2 = c('word','word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word'), 
                 v2_open = c('word','word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word','word',NA,'word'))
```

I am using apply to change observations containing NA to 0 and containing anything else to 1:

```
df <- t(apply(df,1,function(x){
  ifelse(is.na(x) ,0,1)
}))
```

returns

```
      v1 v1_open v2 v2_open
 [1,]  1       1  1       1
 [2,]  0       0  1       1
 [3,]  1       1  0       0
 [4,]  1       1  1       1
 [5,]  0       0  1       1
 [6,]  1       1  0       0
 [7,]  1       1  1       1
 [8,]  0       0  1       1
 [9,]  1       1  0       0
[10,]  1       1  1       1
```

I would like to modify the apply function to exclude columns with names that include the text '_open', resulting in this:

```
      v1 v1_open v2 v2_open
 [1,]  1    word  1    word  
 [2,]  0    NA    1    word  
 [3,]  1    word  0    NA    
 [4,]  1    word  1    word  
 [5,]  0    NA    1    word  
 [6,]  1    word  0    NA    
 [7,]  1    word  1    word  
 [8,]  0    NA    1    word  
 [9,]  1    word  0    NA    
[10,]  1    word  1    word
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-contains("_open")),
            ~ +(!is.na(.)))
```

Output:

```
   v1 v1_open v2 v2_open
1   1    word  1    word
2   0    <NA>  1    word
3   1    word  0    <NA>
4   1    word  1    word
5   0    <NA>  1    word
6   1    word  0    <NA>
7   1    word  1    word
8   0    <NA>  1    word
9   1    word  0    <NA>
10  1    word  1    word
```

Answer (score 1):

We can directly apply the `is.na` on the subset of columns of data.frame without any loop and then update the columns

```
nm1 <- grep("_open", names(df), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
df[nm1] <- +(!is.na(df[nm1]))
df
#   v1 v1_open v2 v2_open
#1   1    word  1    word
#2   0    <NA>  1    word
#3   1    word  0    <NA>
#4   1    word  1    word
#5   0    <NA>  1    word
#6   1    word  0    <NA>
#7   1    word  1    word
#8   0    <NA>  1    word
#9   1    word  0    <NA>
#10  1    word  1    word
```

Answer (score 0):

If your columns alternate between `.*` and `.*_open` then you can simply subset the columns via `TRUE, FALSE`, i.e.

```
df[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- +(!is.na(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)]))

df
#   v1 v1_open v2 v2_open
#1   1    word  1    word
#2   0    <NA>  1    word
#3   1    word  0    <NA>
#4   1    word  1    word
#5   0    <NA>  1    word
#6   1    word  0    <NA>
#7   1    word  1    word
#8   0    <NA>  1    word
#9   1    word  0    <NA>
#10  1    word  1    word
```